# Deleting blank spaces from Googledoc Cells

Tags: javascript, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need to add a loop for a googledoc to include deleting blank spaces before an entry. For example, `"  Bob"` after `"Bob"`.

Comment: Do you need to loop through an entire row or Column?

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.javascripter.net/faq/trim.htm, this a great function for trimming white spaces in javascript.  I've used this in google docs js as well.

```
str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
```